# Error Google authentication for YouTube

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, google-authentication

I am trying to upload video from my app to YouTube.
I am following [this tutorial](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/)
And using youtubeHelper library.

User login is works fine but when i click "Allow" in following image

[image]

It gives following error in console

> Error Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "(null)"
>        UserInfo={data=<7b0e2120 22651272 6f722220 3a202260 6e76716e 69345f63  6c69656a 74220a7d>}
>       Error data:
>       {
>           error = "invalid_client";
>       }

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't show your code but i guess, You are using old version like V 2.1 , This issue is come due to you are using old api. V 2.XXX api is already marked as Deprecated. you can see this link to migrating to new version. **[v3/guides/moving_to_oauth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth)**

[image]

In this link **[developers_guide_protocol_error_responses](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses)** Searchwith **401** you will find more detail regarding your error code.

[image]

More Over a guide also says that if you are refering ios 8 you want to refer [youtube-ios-framework](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/youtube-ios-framework/) this framework.

[image]

I hope this information is enough to understand the reason of your error.

Last but not the least, please check your API version and Prefer standard Document by **Google** to use Youtube api.

**[youtube/documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/)**

**Edit** :- For V 3 . please check this as said by google. [ErrorCode](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for reply  @Badal shah..I am using API version3

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya please check edited answer. verify both causes due to 401 error. you have implemented successfully or not. May be you got error due to` youtubesignup required`.

Comment: I already signup with youtube and i also create one channel to make sure signup success.

Comment: ok. then try this once again. create a new `client ID` and set it to `other` instead of  `ios`There might be some issue to setup your client id .

Comment: i also read that stackoverflow post and i set it to others..previously it is as ios

Comment: but i have doubt with client secret id..i can't find that on credential. i generate key and use it as a client id...is it fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103051/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-divyesh-savaliya).

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same error today. User was logged in and got back 401, then I was thinking I logged in quite a time ago, and logged out / logged in and it worked. So my token was just invalidated on server side probably, and I had to get a fresh one..